# PostgreSQL execution plan environment seq scan vs index scan

Tags: postgresql, indexing, explain

I have 2 PostgreSQL installation, one on a Windows laptop (v 9.5) and one on Ubuntu (v 9.2.15).

Both the DB have been created using the same script (including views and indexes), after that the same scripts load the data from the CSV files.

I'm evaluating the EXPLAIN of the same query (quite big and complex) but what is weird is that the very first step of the execution is performing a Bitmap Index Scan (on window) and a Seq Scan (on Ubuntu). While on Window is scanning 260k rows, on ubuntu it scans 1M rows and the performance of the whole query are decreased (on Windows it is executed in 8min, in ubuntu after 1h is still running).

Do you have any experience of such scenarios?

Both the PostgreSQL instances have the default config.

Comment: 1) lack of statistics. 2) there is no such thing as default config. (and the out-of-the-box config is almost always wrong)

Comment: 1) statistics have been updated in both cases 2) default config means postgres has just been installed, no config has been changed, and this applies to both the environments

Comment: @Bagbyte Execution plans can differ between consecutive queries, why would it be a surprise they differ between two totally different systems? 9.2 is much older so it can be generally worse at tasks. All in all it means there's room for improvment and you should try doing just that.

Comment: Bearing in mind that 9.5 was released this year (2016) and 9.2 was released in 2012 it sounds like postgres has improved in the last 4 years maybe?  I understand 9.2.15 was technically released this year but minor updates don't tend to include performance boosts provided by new features.

Comment: It's pretty unfair to compare 9.5 to 9.2. There have been a **lot** of performance improvements - especially in 9.5. You should really compare identical versions. Also if you want to get more detailed answers post the execution plans (e.g. upload them to http://explain.depesz.com) and `create table` statements for all tables involved. Read http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions and add the missing information

Comment: Not only postgres has been improved, the (method for determining the) "default" config has changed, too. (in older versions, the config_as_installed more or less assumed a pizzabox with 32M RAM ;-)